# Отсутствует перевод подсказки в выборе меток в фильтре

Tags: дефект, локализация, фильтрация-вопросов

Отсутствует перевод подсказки в выборе меток в фильтре (слово `or`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Предложил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17917):

> e.g. python or javascript

> Например, python или javascript

Но только вот на Мете тоже есть этот дефект, и тут метки не `python` и `javascript`.

Comment: Перевод утвердил, но строка на скрине другая, т.к. она уже частично переведена. И порядок меток другой.